# CryptoAPI cryptographic service provider (CSP) for this implementation could not be acquired

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to Implement Encryption/Decryption in my application using System.Security.Cryptography. This is my code:

```
private static RSACryptoServiceProvider _RSA;    
RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
cp.KeyContainerName = "WFMService";
cp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
_RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
_RSA.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
```

However, I'm getting an error on line : `_RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);`

The exception is : CryptoAPI cryptographic service provider (CSP) for this implementation could not be acquired

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: The key container probably couldn't be found.

Comment: @Amy: How do I find that?

Comment: @Amy: Thank you. Your reply helped me. The Key container name was wrong. Once I fixed that, it worked.